# Web apps and websites

Tags: web, mobile, desktop

Sorry this may be a really basic question, but if I build a web app would that also function as a normal website that could be visited on a desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will be visible as a normal web in desktop also. 
If you want flexible web site which is visible in both mobile and desktop platforms then you want to build using bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any code that can be parsed by a browser functions as a normal website that could be visited on a desktop.